# How to solve "Error in SVD$u[, 1:dims] : subscript out of bounds" in R programming?

Tags: r, matrix

I am new bees in R programming, can you please help me out for solving the error from the given below code :

```
#import library
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(SnowballC)
library(slam)
library(lsa)

#import text files for preprocessing
text_key<-(Corpus(DirSource('V:\\Work\\R\\Input\\answer_key')))

##pre-processing is started
#do pre-processing of text data of answer
text_key <- tm_map(text_key, stripWhitespace)
text_key <- tm_map(text_key,content_transformer(tolower))
text_key <- tm_map(text_key,removeWords, stopwords("english"))
text_key <- tm_map(text_key, removeNumbers)
text_key <- tm_map(text_key, removePunctuation)

#do stemming of douments
text_key <- tm_map(text_key,stemDocument,language="english")
text_key <- tm_map(text_key, stripWhitespace)   # *Stripping whitespace   
text_key <- tm_map(text_key, PlainTextDocument) 

#generate document term matrix
dtm_key <- DocumentTermMatrix(text_key)

#print the output of documenttermmatrix
dtm_key

# #inspect the element in document term matrix
inspect(dtm_key)

# #generate wirdcoud for twi dicument term matrix for answer-sheets
m <- as.matrix(dtm_key)

am <- lw_logtf(am) * gw_idf(am)

space <- lsa(am, dims = dimcalc_raw())
```

I have to generate my matrix into Semantic space using LSA but I face the error of SVD subscription out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the silly mistake which to be change to

```
# #generate wirdcoud for twi dicument term matrix for answer-sheets
m <- as.matrix(dtm_key)

am <- lw_logtf(am) * gw_idf(am)
```

I change the variable to the "am" replace with "m" variable.

```
 am <- lw_logtf(m) * gw_idf(m)
```

This is the change variable and I solve.